# Allow outgoing connections

Tags: switch, troubleshooting, acl, arista

I have an Arista switch (EOS) and I'm having trouble allowing outgoing connection from the switch to the outside. Using tcpdump I can see that no packets are being allowed. This has an impact on DNS resolution, email alerts, etc.

How can I allow the switch to make external connections?

This is my current access-list (default):

```
IP Access List default-control-plane-acl [readonly]
    statistics per-entry
    10 permit icmp any any
    20 permit ip any any tracked
    30 permit udp any any eq bfd ttl eq 255
    40 permit udp any any eq bfd-echo ttl eq 254
    50 permit ospf any any
    60 permit tcp any any eq ssh telnet www snmp bgp https msdp
    70 permit udp any any eq bootps bootpc snmp rip ntp
    80 permit tcp any any eq mlag ttl eq 255
    90 permit udp any any eq mlag ttl eq 255
    100 permit vrrp any any
    110 permit ahp any any
    120 permit pim any any
    130 permit igmp any any
    140 permit tcp any any range 5900 5910
    150 permit tcp any any range 50000 50100
    160 permit udp any any range 51000 51100
```

Comment: What connections to you want to allow (besides DNS)?

Comment: Maybe a connection to the internal mail server but that's not critical. I'm mostly interested in making DNS work.

Comment: Can you confirm where this acl is applied?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score -2):

**DNS Workaround**
ip host mail.example.com 1.1.1.1

[image]

Comment: How can setting static DNS entries be a solution here?

Comment: The [comment](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18874/when-is-ibgp-used/18892#comment28338_18892) from @JohnJensen seems appropriate again

Comment: DNS and email alerts are failing due to DNS resolution port(s) getting blocked. Configuring the hostname(s) of target servers locally bypasses DNS resolution and fixes the issue.

Comment: To be honest, this is a horrible suggestion. Unless you know every single address ever needed and you're sure they will never ever change, this will introduce more problems than it solves.

Comment: Horrible?  We are talking about traffic to/from the switch, not through it.  The mail server is not going to change names often is it?  Can you give me an example of what types of addresses you are talking about?

Comment: A simple example: dns lookups for hosts connecting to management services like SSH. Unless you're absolutely sure what DNS queries the device does, a static host list won't work. So the bottomline is: you don't answer his question, you give bad advice on how to some sort of workaround.

Comment: SSH to or from the switch console does not require DNS, right?  Or can you explain?

Comment: Some devices do DNS lookups for hosts connecting to them, for example to log hostnames instead of IPs.

Comment: Admin terminals don't have FQDN's.  I routinely connect to unix/linux endpoints with SSH using a FQDN but the terminal itself does not require DNS itself.  Your example is far fetched and your characterization of my suggestion/answer as horrible is off-base.  I would appreciate it if you reconsidered my solution.  Sure, one can find possibilities where it might not fit but practically it just may be an elegant fix.  I think 'horrible' is not a fair characterization.